# PreviewMouseMove firing twice

Tags: c#, wpf, mousemove

I have a problem with a simple code. I was looking for a few hours a solution, but no effects.
I have a Canvas and Rectangle. I move Rectangle, if the cursor is outside, delegate pMouseMove fires only once for each pixel. Conversely, if the cursor is at the Rectangle, delagate fires twice for each pixel. I want to run it only once, as if it were outside the Rectangle, how to do it?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Canvas x:Name="Can" Height="257" Width="503" Background="Gray">
    <TextBox Name="tb" Width="77" Height="20" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="-21"/>
  </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    private static int i;
    private static string s;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        rect.Height = 50;
        rect.Width = 50;
        rect.Fill = Brushes.Black;
        Can.Children.Add(rect);
        Can.PreviewMouseMove += pMouseMove;
    }

    private void pMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //cursor over Rectangle
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, e.GetPosition(Can).Y + 10);
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, e.GetPosition(Can).X + 10);

        //cursor outside Rectangle
        //Canvas.SetTop(rect, e.GetPosition(Can).Y - 10);
        //Canvas.SetLeft(rect, e.GetPosition(Can).X - 10);

        //Counter
        i++;
        tb.Text = i.ToString();

        //e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: You should be aware that mouse motion events can also be sent less often than one for every pixel, sometimes much less.  Any logic that depends on the number of mouse move events sent for correctness is broken, although it is reasonable to care about performance.

Answer (score 3):

Events in WPF are [Routed Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx), which effectively means that your `Canvas` will receive events from the canvas itself and everything inside the canvas. As you noticed, the `Canvas`'s `PreviewMouseMove` event is receiving events from both the `Canvas` and the `Rectangle`.

[Update]
I ran your code and added a line to check the value of the `e.OriginalSource` to see what originally raised the event. Like this:

```
private void pMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // print out e.OriginalSource just for learning purposes
    Console.WriteLine("OriginalSource:" + e.OriginalSource.ToString());
}
```

My original answer was to check e.OriginalSource's type because I thought you were receiving the same event twice. But I now see what you are saying: if `e.OriginalSource` is the `Rectangle`, the `PreviewMouseMove` event gets raised twice as often compared to when `e.OriginalSource` is the `Canvas`. There's something internal to the `Rectangle`'s implementation that is doing this (only way to find out is to use a tool like Reflector to see the internal logic. However, there is a workaround where you can make the frequency of the event consistent.

You can set `rect.IsHitTestVisible = false;` and that will eliminate the Rectangle from sending events and being `e.OriginalSource` -- so that means all `PreviewMouseMove` events will come from the `Canvas`. Then you can use `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` to check to see if the mouse position is inside the `Rectangle`.

I just ran this code below and I think this is a way to guarantee consistent raising of events, but still have your hit test capability.

In the constructor:

```
rect.Fill = Brushes.Black;
rect.IsHitTestVisible = false;
Can.Children.Add(rect);
```

In the `PreviewMouseMove` handler:

```
private void pMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Debug.WriteLine(e.OriginalSource.ToString());

    HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(rect, e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement));

    if (result != null) {
        Debug.WriteLine("Mouse inside rect")
    }
    else {
        Debug.WriteLine("Mouse outside rect");
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked value of the `e.OriginalSource`. If cursor is over Rectangle, `pMouseMove` fires twice and in both cases the value of the `e.OriginalSource` is `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle`. Thus, the condition `if (e.OriginalSource is Canvas)` is always false.